# How to generate signed apk and deploy to google play store

Tags: react-native

i am using create-react-native-app 
there is no android / iOS folder

how to generate signed apk and deploye to google play store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the instructions for `create-react-native-app` app deployment.

https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/react-native-scripts/template/README.md#sharing-and-deployment

> If you want to build and deploy your app yourself, you'll need to eject from CRNA and use Xcode and Android Studio.
>
> This is usually as simple as running npm run eject in your project, which will walk you through the process. Make sure to install react-native-cli and follow the native code getting started guide for React Native.

Generating key
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

If you don't see android/ios folders in your directory. Then type in your terminal `react-native upgrade` then `react-native link`

Comment: if i follow this instructions its deploying in expo server,  i want to generate signed .apk file which i camn use for deploy on google play store

Comment: Yes, the instructions are there, I'll update answer to add it.

Comment: yes i  have installed  react-native-cli  already and if eject from CRNA then i how can i add android .iOS folder to my project

Comment: Try `react-native link`, if you get error do `react-native upgrade`, this will create android/ios folders